# Wireshark - permission problem in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, wireshark

I installed `wireshark` (`tshark`) using

```
sudo apt-get install tshark
```

this installed the `tshark` executable in `/usr/bin/tshark`.

The problem now is that I am unable to run it without root permissions. How can I execute this command using the permissions of a normal user?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to configure wireshark to allow non-root-users to capture packets:

```
dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
```

Add yourself to the `wireshark` group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G wireshark "$USER"
```

Restart your system so the group permissions will be applied. Now you can start wireshark and capture some packets!

Comment: Restart/Log-Out and Log-In on the system, for user permissions to be effectively applied.

Answer (score 3):

The Wireshark [wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Security#head-ac69042aeeb98cdaed2ec2ff1bd2c983fa03cffd) discusses permissions and ways to "circumvent" them if needed - although I'm pretty sure that any packet capturing on Linux would require root at some level.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with not being able to see any network interfaces when running Wireshark (tshark's GUI cousin) as a non-root user. Nowadays, Ubuntu and Debian support file capabilities with which I was able to get Wireshark (and tshark) running as non-root.

1. Create a wireshark group.

   ```
   sudo groupadd wireshark
   ```
2. Add your username to the wireshark group.

   ```
   sudo usermod -a -G wireshark yourusername
   ```
3. Change group ownership of dumpcap to wireshark group.

   ```
   sudo chgrp wireshark /usr/bin/dumpcap
   ```
4. Set file permissions of dumpcap to 754 (rwx for user, r-x for group).

   ```
   sudo chmod 754 /usr/bin/dumpcap
   ```
5. Enable file capabilities for dumpcap.

   ```
   sudo setcap 'CAP_NET_RAW+eip CAP_NET_ADMIN+eip' /usr/bin/dumpcap
   ```
6. You may also need to run `dpkg-reconfigure` for wireshark-common if you install Wireshark or tshark as a package through Synaptic and enable packet capture for non-root users.

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
   ```

Comment: refer to the great [wireshark wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges) regarding capture privileges. Look at the section titled, "Limiting capture permission to only one group"...

Comment: the wireshark group and the permissions will be set by `dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common`

Answer (score 0):

It will probably need root credential to put the network card into premiscious mode.  You need to set the user id http://www.zzee.com/solutions/linux-permissions.shtml#setuid or run it with sudo.  Sudo is the better, more secure, option.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think 'sudo is the better, more secure option'. Also if you start Wireshark like that on Debian/Ubuntu, you'll get all kinds of nasty error messages.